# Как правильно удалить элемент из NodeList?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть `NodeList` внутри которого элементы которые отображаются на странице:

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
```

И при клике на первый элемент `elements` мне необходимо его удалить и добавить элемент из другого `NodeList` в конец `elements`.

Как лучше всего провести вышеописанную операцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно из NodeList нельзя удалять элемент. Можно сделать из него массив и работать с массивом. Что-то около того:

```js
let elements = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.element') );
let other = document.querySelectorAll('.other');
let i = 0;

nodeListDemo(elements);

elements[0].onclick = bubu;

function bubu(){
  this.onclick = null;
  this.classList.remove('nodeList'); // удалил демо-класс с кликнутого элемента

  elements.shift();                  // удалил первый элемент из elements
  elements.push( other[i++] );       // добавил другой элемент с конца
  
  nodeListDemo(elements);            // всё, что стало зеленым - принадлежит elements
  elements[0].onclick = bubu;        // первый элемент уже другой - обработчик на него.
}

function nodeListDemo(elems){
  elems.forEach( e => e.classList.add('nodeList') );
}
```

```css
.element, .other {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
}

.other { background-color: #f36700; }

.nodeList {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<hr>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
<div class="other"></div>
```

Но в таком виде задача выглядит сликом искусственно. Не помешало бы добавить контекст задачи в вопросе.